# How to initialize UICollectionViewCell programmatically without Nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I decided to opt out of using a Xib to generate my custom `UICollectionViewCell` (`StoneCell`), so I've been struggling with how to go about properly initializing it programmatically.

I implemented:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size = [MainScreen screen];
    CGFloat width = size.width;
    CGFloat item = (width*60)/320;
    return CGSizeMake(item, item);
}
```

as well as:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[StoneCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"stoneCell"];
```

in my `UICollectionView` controller.

In my `StoneCell.m`, I tried the following:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        StoneCell* stone = [[StoneCell alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self = stone;
    }
    return self;
 }
```

but to no avail.  When I build and run, I crash on `self = [super initWithFrame:frame];`   When I check the value of frame, it's correctly set at `{{0,0},{70,70}}` which is what it should be on the 6s.  However, the object `stone` (as well as `self`) are both reported as `nil`.

Clearly this is not correct, so I wanted to know how to initialize the cell properly.

I am also properly dequeuing the cell in:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

so that's taken care of.

Comment: Have you inherit your StoneCell from UICollectionViewCell ?

Comment: Yes, definitively yes.

Comment: Silly question, did you confirm that you correctly set your datasource and delegate properly for the CollectionView? Also, you might consider just adding a prototype cell to your collectionview if you have that on a storyboard and then telling that prototype cell that it is of the class StoneCell.

Comment: Yea they're correctly set.  Also, I'm not using Storyboard of Xib, just straight code.  Previously I used a Xib, but I couldn't find a way to change the height and width of the cell (unless there is a way).

Answer (score 0):

Your initializer should be

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    return self;
 }
```

With your original implementation

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        StoneCell* stone = [[StoneCell alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self = stone;
    }
    return self;
 }
```

you have an infinite recursion of `initWithFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

// In  `AMAImageViewCell.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AMAImageViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

// In  AMAImageViewCell.m

```
@implementation AMAImageViewCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];

        _imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        _imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

        _imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;

        [self.contentView addSubview:_imageView];
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

/******In the class where you have to use **********/

```
 [self.collectionView registerClass:[AMAImageViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:ImageCellIdentifier];
```

// In cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
AMAImageViewCell *cell = [collectionViewLocal dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ImageCellIdentifier
                                                                  forIndexPath:indexPath];
```